# C# 2D Game multiple keys doesnt work

Tags: c#, winforms

I know this question is asked many times but i havent found the right answer for my problem.

My problem is i have a WinForm and i like to press multiple keys to make something xD but if i try to press numpad7, 8 and 4 or any other combination
then it wont work it shows just nothing but i have pressed all this keys

i have tried this

```
private void GameScreen_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        try {
            switch (e.KeyCode) {
                case Keys.NumPad0:
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
                    changeButtonsColor();
                    break;
                case Keys.NumPad1:
                    gb_7.BackColor = Color.MediumSpringGreen;
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
                    break;
                case Keys.NumPad2:
                    gb_8.BackColor = Color.MediumSpringGreen;
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
                    break;
                case Keys.NumPad3:
                    gb_9.BackColor = Color.MediumSpringGreen;
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
                    break;
                case Keys.NumPad4:
                    gb_4.BackColor = Color.MediumSpringGreen;
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
                    break;
                case Keys.NumPad5:
                    gb_5.BackColor = Color.MediumSpringGreen;
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
                    break;
                case Keys.NumPad6:
                    gb_6.BackColor = Color.MediumSpringGreen;
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
                    break;
                case Keys.NumPad7:
                    gb_1.BackColor = Color.MediumSpringGreen;
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
                    break;
                case Keys.NumPad8:
                    gb_2.BackColor = Color.MediumSpringGreen;
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
                    break;
                case Keys.NumPad9:
                    gb_3.BackColor = Color.MediumSpringGreen;
                    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            Console.WriteLine("fail");
        }
    }
```

please help me...

Comment: The first thing to test is whether or not this is a symptom of keyboard "ghosting", which is a problem where the keyboard is only set up to register a certain number/combination of keys at a time. [Here is a page](https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx) explaining the problem which also includes a nice tool for testing the your keyboard for ghosting issues (at the top of the page). If you are able to see all of the keys register in that tool at the same time then it is a software problem, but it would be best to test your hardware first

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This cannot be fixed.  Because of how keyboards work, you can press 2 keys at the same time, but as soon as you start pressing 3 at a time, only certain combinations will work.  There is no way you can modify the coding to fix this, unless you change what keys you are pressing.